# What is the difference between installing Rubygems "locally" and "system wide"?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am running RHEL 6.2 on a VM (I have no control over it).  I would like to use Ruby along with Mysql to do the work I need to do.  But right now the server does not have the mysql gem installed.  It doesn't even have ruby gems installed.  So I can't simply do `gem install mysql`.  The people maintaining the server suggested I do local install of ruby gems.  Is there a benefit to this?  What if the server is hosting a web application that consists of code depending on a gem? Will this effect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either in `~/.gem` (local) or in `/usr/lib/ruby` (system). Locally installed gems are accessible by you only, system gems everyone can use.

Comment: I think installing system wide is a better option since there will be other users that will need to use it as well.  Thank you.